# How to implement index-core style indexed state monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to understand indexed monads in the [`index-core`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/index-core) style.  I have become stuck in a paradox which is that I can't understand the principles until I have constructed a few examples, and I can't construct examples until I understand the principles.

I am trying to construct an indexed state monad.  So far my intuition tells me it should be something like this

```hs
type a :* b = forall i. (a i, b i)
newtype IState f a i = IState { runIState :: f i -> (a :* f) }
```

and that I can recover the "restricted" state monad by setting `f = Identity` and choosing `a` appropriately:

```
type IState' s s' a = IState Identity (a := s') s
```

But I'm feeling rather lost.  Can someone confirm that I'm on the right lines?

I'm using [a similar question on the indexed continuation monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014683/how-to-implement-index-core-style-indexed-continuation-monad) as a guide, but I don't think it's really close enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can replicate Gabriel's argument from the indexed `Cont` answer linked. If the standard index state monad is

```
State s s' a = s -> (a, s')
```

then we generalize it in stages. First by using `Identity` to reflect the concrete types `s` and `s'` as fibers in the indexed type space `Identity`.

```
State s s' a = s          -> (a, s')
             ~ Identity s -> (a, Identity s')
```

then by generalizing the value type `a` to an indexed type as well over the "destination" index, the type `s'`.

```
             ~ Identity s -> (a   , Identity s')
             ~ Identity s -> (a s', Identity s')
```

and then by using an existential type to erase the destination index. We'll recover it later.

```
data a :* b = forall i . P (a i) (b i)

  Identity s -> (a s', Identity s') 
~ Identity s -> P a Identity
```

Finally, we'll note that `Identity` is the indexed type of the state space and `a` the indexed type of the value space, so we can write `IState` as

```
newtype IState s -- indexed state space
               a -- indexed value space
               i -- index
  = IState { runIState :: s i -> a :* s }
--   State { runState  :: s   -> (a, s) }        for comparison
```

---

Why use an existentially quantified pair instead of a universally quantified one? A first nudge comes from the fact that the index associated with `a` is occurring positively in `IState` while it appeared negatively in `ICont`. A second hint comes from writing `returnI`. If we use the universally quantified version and try to write `returnI`

```
newtype IState' s a i = IState' { runIState' :: s i -> (forall i . (a i, s i)) }

returnI :: a i -> IState' s a i
returnI a = IState' (\si -> (?forget a, ?forget si))
```

we would need to have this `forget` function which forgets all of the information about the index.

However, if we instead use the existentially quantified pair then it's up to the constructor of that returning pair, i.e. the implementor of the `IState` value, to pick the index. This lets us instantiate `IFunctor` and `IMonad`

```
instance IFunctor (IState s) where
  -- fmapI :: (a :-> b) -> IState s a :-> IState s b
  fmapI phi (IState go) = IState $ \si -> 
    case go si of 
      P ax sx -> P (phi ax) sx

instance IMonad (IState s) where
  -- returnI :: a :-> IState s a
  return ai = IState (\si -> P ai si)

  -- bindI :: (a :-> IState s b) -> (IState s a :-> IState s b)
  bindI f m = IState $ \s ->
    case runIState m s of
      P ax sx -> runIState (f ax) sx
```

The only downside to the use of this existential pair is that it's... pretty hard to actually use. For instance, we'd really like to be able to use the "pointed" indexed type constructor `(:=)` in order to fix a known index and project out of the existential pair.

```
one :: (a := i :* b) -> a
two :: (a := i :* b) -> b i
```

Unfortunately, Haskell isn't smart enough to coerce the existential even when we know what it it is, so the second of these projections has an unsavory implementation

```
one :: (a := i :* b) -> a
one (P (V a) _) = a

two :: (a := i :* b) -> b i
two (P _ s) = unsafeCoerce s
```

---

Finally, the proof is in the pudding. We can use `IState` to implement the standard complement of stateful effects we're used to seeing.

```
-- Higher order unit type
data U1 a = U1

put :: s i -> IState s U1 j
put s = IState (\_ -> P U1 s)

get :: IState s s i
get = IState (\s -> P s s)
```

and use them to implement some general higher order combinators such as modify (which needs an explicit type signature, but you can compute that from the implementation manually with some thought)

```
modify :: (s :-> s) -> IState s U1 i
modify f = get ?>= put . f
```

However, additionally to these, we have other ways of representing the combinators that are more explicit about the indexing due to restriction via `(:=)`. This can be useful in order to pass around more information about the indexing.

```
put' :: s i1 -> IState s (() := i1) i
put' s = IState (\_ -> P (V ()) s)

get' :: IState s (s i := i) i
get' = IState (\s -> P (V s) s)

modify' :: (s -> s) -> IState (s := j) (() := j) i
modify' f = get >>= put' . V . f

modify'' :: (s i -> s k) -> IState s (() := k) i
modify'' f = get' >>= put' . f
```

Finally, we can use all this to implement an example. For instance, we can build the indexed type over file handle states not that it's tremendously useful.

```
data Open
data Closed
data Any a

data St where
  So :: Int -> St Open
  Sc ::        St Closed
  Sa :: a   -> St (Any a)

getAny :: St (Any a) -> a
getAny (Sa a) = a
```

Then we can build

```
open :: String -> File Closed Open ()
open name = put' (SOpen $ getHandle name) where
  getHandle = length

close :: File Open Closed ()
close = put' SClosed

getHandle :: File Open Open Int
getHandle = do
  SOpen i <- get'
  return i

putA :: a -> File x (Any a) ()
putA a = put' (SAny a)
```

where

```
open "foo" >> close                -- typechecks
open "foo" >> close >> close       -- fails
open "foo" >> getHandler >> close  -- typechecks
open "foo" >> close >> getHandler  -- fails
```

and things like

```
> one $ runIState (do putA 4
                      sa <- get'
                      return (getAny sa)) Sc
4
> one $ runIState (do putA ()
                      sa <- get'
                      return (getAny sa)) Sc
()
> one $ runIState (do putA 4
                      putA ()
                      sa <- get'
                      return (getAny sa)) Sc
()
```

all work.

Comment: Wouldn't an existentially quantified pair prevent you from returning in multiple possible states?

Comment: I'm re-reading the paper to try to be more competent with my answer and realizing that Conor's pun implies that using indexed monads like this is suicide, fwiw. Or perhaps homicide against C.

Comment: I think in order to return on multiple types you'll need something like `one :: (a := i) :* b -> b i; one (P a b) = unsafeCoerce b`. Then you can augment your state indexed type with an index like `data Any a` with `SA :: a -> St (Any a)`.

Comment: Not the prettiest, but at least you don't have to go all the way as far as to implement the free monad over indexed types.

Comment: I've taken the time to understand your answer and I think it's perfect.  My comment about returning in multiple states was a red herring.

Comment: A few corrections/suggestions.  Do you want to make these?  If not I'm happy to.  It would be good to have a flawless answer on this topic as it's extremely puzzling!  Then I'll accept your answer.  1. `runIState (go s)` should be `runIState m s`.  2. You can make a `get` and `modify'` with stronger guarantees: `get :: IState s (s i := i) i; get = IState (\s -> E (V s) s)`; `modify' :: (s i -> s j) -> IState s (() := j) i; modify' f = get' !>= (\a -> put (f a))`

Comment: This was mostly done on my phone with a little hesitation, so I can spruce up the answer in a few hours both with a little more fleshed out description and a more complete example.

Comment: Greatly expanded now! Let me know how it reads and feel free to edit whatever makes sense.

Comment: I'm throwing these up into a library to canonize them a bit and work out refinements. Please feel free to contribute anything you find as well—https://github.com/tel/index-basic